# Dynamic formula based on number of cells with inputs

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I have a specific use case - a Google Sheets I've set up with multiple people in which we keep track of games we periodically play in multiplayer/coop.

Each person has a corresponding column with an "x" marking each of the owned games (represented in rows). It looks something like this:

```
            Person X    Person Y    Person Z
Game A                     x           x
Game B          x                      x
Game C          x          x           x
```

I also have a separate set of columns with votes for that certain game (from 0 to 5):

```
            Person X    Person Y    Person Z    Person X    Person Y    Person Z
Game A                     x           x                       5           2
Game B          x                      x            5                      3
Game C          x          x           x            3          3           3
```

These ratings make up a "score" for each game, and the game with the highest score gets played when we meet up (democracy, yay!).

The formula I'm currently using is a simple arithmetic mean of the ratings. In order to display a percentage (100% being a vote of 5 from all participants), I use percentage formatting and divide the sum by a multiple of 5 in the formula. If there are 6 votes I will divide by 30, and get a value ranging from 0 to 100% for each row. But:

- using the same formula for all rows means that empty cells are calculated as a vote of "0" which seems unfair
- using a custom formula (and dividing by custom multiples of 5) is, of course, tedious and cumbersome for 300+ rows

**I would like to have this formula be dynamic** - and divide according to either the number of votes added (second set of columns) or the number of people who own the game (first set of columns) - not exactly sure at this point.

If there are only 4 votes (or x's) - I should divide by 20. How can I do that in a scalable and efficient way?

Comment: Kind of embarrassing, but sure: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/10UQFFIvXftXMAC1tHKJUMNGUmDG-34bqmZ5GZz4AMcY/edit#gid=0. 

I've eliminated some columns and anonymized some stuff. The "W" column is the place where I calculate the score for each row.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
=IF(COUNTBLANK(Q2:V2)=0, SUM(Q2:V2)/30,
 IF(COUNTBLANK(Q2:V2)=1, SUM(Q2:V2)/25,
 IF(COUNTBLANK(Q2:V2)=2, SUM(Q2:V2)/20,
 IF(COUNTBLANK(Q2:V2)=3, SUM(Q2:V2)/15,
 IF(COUNTBLANK(Q2:V2)=4, SUM(Q2:V2)/10,
 IF(COUNTBLANK(Q2:V2)=5, SUM(Q2:V2)/5,))))))
```

[image: 0]